# Implement timeout in windows filecopy

Tags: python, winapi, timeout, pywin32

I want to copy a list of files on windows using python. When doing that manually, I see timeouts in some files, therefore the copy process fails. I need a way to implement the timeout check in python.

So far I use the win32 API:

```
import win32file
files = {'source_a' : 'dest_a', 'source_b' : 'dest_b'}

for f in files.keys():
    win32file.CopyFileW(f,files[f],0)
```

In some cases, the `CopyFileW` function doesn't return in "reasonable time", for the sake of this discussion, let's say 5 seconds. How can I wrap this function to be checked against a timer?

**Edit:** As suggested, I switched over to using the `CopyFileEx` function, because it has a cancellation Interface. If I put a timeout check in the callback function, the copy process is stalled as long as the callback is running. As I understand, the calls to the callback function only are issued, when there IS some file copying activity. If there ISN'T for a longer time, I don't see that.

Comment: A more precise formulation of the remaining questions as well as a very concise answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203579/cancel-a-stalled-file-copy-in-python-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `CopyFile`, use [`CopyFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx) which provides an interface that supports cancellation.

Comment: Does this take over Metadata as well? (As CopyFileW does?)

Comment: Yes it does. That fact is clearly stated in the documentation to which I linked. Please take the time to read it all.

Comment: @Dschoni - `CopyFile(lpExistingFileName,lpNewFileName,bFailIfExists)` implementation simply call `CopyFileEx(lpExistingFileName,lpNewFileName,0,0,0, bFailIfExists ? COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS : 0);` usual windows api practic - if `fn` and `fnEx` api exist - `fn` call `fnEx` with extra parameters set to default values (in most case to 0)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your suggestion points me in the right direction. However, cancellation from another thread (which I understand is needed for timeout checks) results in a `pywintypes.error` (File is in use).

Comment: I'd supply a callback function and do the timeout checks there, to avoid having to create a separate thread just to check timeouts.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem I'm having. I'll specify my question.