# Cancel a stalled file copy in python on windows

Tags: python, windows, callback, copy, timeout

On windows, I want to copy a bunch of files over a network with Python. Sometimes, the network is not responding, and the copy is stalled. I want to check, if that happens, and skip the file in question, when that happens. By asking this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063906/implement-timeout-in-windows-filecopy), I found out about the [CopyFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx) function, that allows the use of a callback function, that can abort the file copy.

The implementation in Python looks like that:

```
import win32file

def Win32_CopyFileEx( ExistingFileName, NewFileName, Canc = False):
    win32file.CopyFileEx(
        ExistingFileName,                             # PyUNICODE           | File to be copied
        NewFileName,                                  # PyUNICODE           | Place to which it will be copied
        Win32_CopyFileEx_ProgressRoutine,             # CopyProgressRoutine | A python function that receives progress updates, can be None
        Data = None,                                  # object              | An arbitrary object to be passed to the callback function
        Cancel = Canc,                                # boolean             | Pass True to cancel a restartable copy that was previously interrupted
        CopyFlags = win32file.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE,  # int                 | Combination of COPY_FILE_* flags
        Transaction = None                            # PyHANDLE            | Handle to a transaction as returned by win32transaction::CreateTransaction
        )
```

From the documentation of the CopyFileEx function, I can see two possibilities of cancelation of a running copy.

> **pbCancel [in, optional]** If this flag is set to **TRUE** during the copy operation, the operation is canceled. Otherwise, the copy
>   operation will continue to completion.

I could not figure out a way how to do that. I tried calling the same function with the same file handles again but with the cancel flag set to `TRUE`, but that leads in an error, because of the file in question being in use by another process.

Another possibility seems to be the callback function:

> **lpProgressRoutine [in, optional]** The address of a callback function of
>   type LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE that is called each time another portion of
>   the file has been copied. This parameter can be NULL. For more
>   information on the progress callback function, see the
>   CopyProgressRoutine function.

The [documentation of this ProgressRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363854.aspx) states, that this callback is either called when the copy is started or when a junk of the file is finished copying. The callback function can cancel the copy process if it returns `1` or `2` ( cancel, stop). However, this callback function seems to not being called, when the copy of a junk is stalled.

So my question is: How I can cancel this copy on a per-file-basis when it is stalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`win32file.CopyFileEx`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32file__CopyFileEx_meth.html) doesn't allow passing `Cancel` as anything but a boolean or integer value. In the API it's an `LPBOOL` pointer, which allows the caller to set its value concurrently in another thread. You'll have to use ctypes, Cython, or a C extension to get this level of control. Below I've written an example using ctypes.

If canceling the copy doesn't work because the thread is blocked on synchronous I/O, you can try calling [`CancelIoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363792) on the file handles that you're passed in the progress routine, or [`CancelSynchronousIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363794) to cancel all synchronous I/O for the thread. These I/O cancel functions were added in Windows Vista. They're not available in Windows XP, in case you're still supporting it.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS              = 0x0001
COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE                 = 0x0002
COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE       = 0x0004
COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x0008
COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK                = 0x0800
COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING                = 0x1000

CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0
CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH  = 1
PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0
PROGRESS_CANCEL   = 1
PROGRESS_STOP     = 2
PROGRESS_QUIET    = 3

ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED = 0x04D3

if not hasattr(wintypes, 'LPBOOL'):
    wintypes.LPBOOL = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BOOL)

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _Retval_
    wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER, # _In_     TotalFileSize
    wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER, # _In_     TotalBytesTransferred
    wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER, # _In_     StreamSize
    wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER, # _In_     StreamBytesTransferred
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_     dwStreamNumber
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_     dwCallbackReason
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_     hSourceFile
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_     hDestinationFile
    wintypes.LPVOID)        # _In_opt_ lpData

kernel32.CopyFileExW.errcheck = _check_bool
kernel32.CopyFileExW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,   # _In_     lpExistingFileName
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,   # _In_     lpNewFileName
    LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE, # _In_opt_ lpProgressRoutine
    wintypes.LPVOID,    # _In_opt_ lpData
    wintypes.LPBOOL,    # _In_opt_ pbCancel
    wintypes.DWORD)     # _In_     dwCopyFlags

@LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE
def debug_progress(tsize, ttrnsfr, stsize, sttrnsfr, stnum, reason,
                  hsrc, hdst, data):
    print('ttrnsfr: %d, stnum: %d, stsize: %d, sttrnsfr: %d, reason: %d' %
          (ttrnsfr, stnum, stsize, sttrnsfr, reason))
    return PROGRESS_CONTINUE

def copy_file(src, dst, cancel=None, flags=0, 
              cbprogress=None, data=None):
    if isinstance(cancel, int):
        cancel = ctypes.byref(wintypes.BOOL(cancel))
    elif cancel is not None:
        cancel = ctypes.byref(cancel)
    if cbprogress is None:
        cbprogress = LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE()
    kernel32.CopyFileExW(src, dst, cbprogress, data, cancel, flags)
```

**Example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import tempfile
    import threading

    src_fd, src = tempfile.mkstemp()
    os.write(src_fd, os.urandom(16 * 2 ** 20))
    os.close(src_fd)
    dst = tempfile.mktemp()

    cancel = wintypes.BOOL(False)
    t = threading.Timer(0.001, type(cancel).value.__set__, (cancel, True))
    t.start()
    try:
        copy_file(src, dst, cancel, cbprogress=debug_progress)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
        assert e.winerror == ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED
    finally:
        if os.path.exists(src):
            os.remove(src)
        if os.path.exists(dst):
            os.remove(dst)
```

Comment: Just: Wow. It's a lot harder than I originally thought. I'll put a link to this answer in my related one.