# How to put a timeout on an I/O transaction and cancel it under python/windows?

Tags: python, winapi, io, multiprocessing, pywin32

I have occasionally problematic SD cards where individual files are not copyable, but also no error appears, only after sometimes errors. The tools I use for copying are also not re-acting during that waiting time. They cannot be killed. Only removing the SD card reader helps. I am using Windows currently.
Hence, I am trying to write a tool that skips file copying operations after a timeout by cancelling the blocking I/O operation.

I have of course tried to write some code which kills a process after some time, but as already mentioned, this does not work even with admin rights. So I tried to use the low level operations of Windows in order to submit and, if needed, also cancel I/O operations, and I found pywin32 to be handy (but only little documented) API under python. Unfortunately, it is not working at expected. Neither the win32 methods work as expected (e.g. ignoring time outs, non-working transaction identifier), nor Python multiprocessing capabilities are useful. In contrast, they result to be an obstacle (no direct passing of handles between threads is possible). Here is my code so far (copied together from different sources):

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import win32file,win32transaction
def win32copy(src,dst,transactions):
    transaction=win32transaction.CreateTransaction(Timeout=5000) #the timeout could have been a solution, but has absolutely no effect
    transactions.append(str(win32transaction.GetTransactionId(transaction))) #the transaction itself is not pickable
    win32file.CopyFileEx(src, dst, Transaction=transaction) #the I/O block already happens here, surprisingly, and not later at the commit
    win32transaction.CommitTransactionAsync(transaction) #that is never reached. Hence, doesn't matter if CommitTransaction() or CommitTransactionAsync()is used 
    print "transaction submitted"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    transactions = manager.list() # for sharing objects between threads
    src='D:\\sdcard\\somefile'
    dst='C:\\harddisk\\somefile'
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=win32copy, args=(src,dst,transactions))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(10) #sleep for 10sec
    print "waiting finished"
    while p.is_alive():
        print "running... let's kill it...",transactions[0] #here is the GUID as string
        transaction=win32transaction.OpenTransaction(0x12003F,transactions[0]) #got the first parameter from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/bd6b7f9ad54c2ce268674eab2b74dce625fb13dd/win32/Lib/winnt.py
        #error: pywintypes.error: (6715, 'OpenTransaction',...'Could not find transaction object') 
        win32file.CancelIo(transaction) #not reached, can't tell if it would work
        p.terminate() #doesn't work, process is un-killable
```

As I commented, the current code fails at retrieving the transaction handle in the main python process, because it says that it could not find the transaction object. I had to go the way of the GUID because python cannot pickle PyHANDLE objects directly. So, a solution would be a way to pass the object between the processes. On the other hand, I am quite sceptical that this alone is the reason it fails. I would also be fine with any solution that allows me to cancel the copy operations after a pre-determined time.
I also tried the solution of [notifying by setting a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42210819/12027823) passed to CopyFileExW proposed by @Eryk Sun and @DrakeWu-MSFT but this also did not cancel the operation.

Comment: Can you add the stack traces of the errors you encountered?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203579/cancel-a-stalled-file-copy-in-python-on-windows

Comment: `CopyFileEx` not take handle to Transaction and have another arguments. CancelIo accept only handle to the file

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments.
@razdi : The stack trace says on transaction=win32transaction.OpenTransaction(0x12003F,transactions[0]): pywintypes.error: (6715, 'OpenTransaction', 'Das angegebene Transaction-Objekt konnte nicht ge\xf6ffnet werden, da es nicht gefunden wurde.') which means that the transaction object was not opened because it was not found.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: That was promising, but it does not work (for my corrupt file), my stick still blinks and the operation can only be cancelled by pulling it out. My interpretation is that the cancel variable is set, but it has no effect. Here is the output of the progress:
ttrnsfr: 0, stnum: 1, stsize: 2119665, sttrnsfr: 0, reason: 1
ttrnsfr: 524288, stnum: 1, stsize: 2119665, sttrnsfr: 524288, reason: 0
The "reason" changes but I do not know what it is.

Comment: @RbMm : Then I do not understand the usage. What is the transaction argument in CopyFileEx, and what should be the file handle be in CancelIo, the source or the destination file (both somehow does not make sense to me, since it only described one end of the transaction)? And what is the effect of the timeout in CreateTransaction, or what does this in general do, for what is it good for?

Comment: `CopyFileExW` have not  transaction argument. probably you confused it with `CopyFileTransactedW`. `CancelIo` take any file handle, but why you decide use it here ? you really have not file handles

Comment: In the win32file API it has, see the [doc](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__CopyFileEx_meth.html) and [source code](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/win32/src/win32file.i). It says that CopyFileTransacted is (internally) executed if a transaction is given. The motivation behind specifying a transaction was that I could cancel the transaction then. Do you have a proposal how to do it not using transactions or how to use the file handles for cancelling the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

`reason` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203579/cancel-a-stalled-file-copy-in-python-on-windows/42210819#42210819) is a parameter in call back [CopyProgressRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa). 0 means Another part of the data file was copied, 1 means Another stream was created and is about to be copied. This is the callback reason given when the callback routine is first invoked.

Each parameter of `debug_programs` corresponds to the parameters of callback function in the document.

Determine whether `StreamBytesTransferred` has changed compared with the value in previous callback, and `dwCallbackReason == 0`, Then decide to return `PROGRESS_CANCEL`.

If the callback function is also blocking, I suspect that the problem is not on file I/O, but there may be a deadlock internal. Maybe you should try read file first and then write to a new file if the file is readable.